# Converting multiple xls files to xlsx- issues with scaling up from single file

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

We have a few thousand xls files, with dozens of sheets in each file.  We are working on a larger project to combine the files and sheets, but first need to convert them to xlsx.

The following code works fine on a single file:

```
 import xlrd
 from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook as openpyxlWorkbook

 xlsBook = xlrd.open_workbook(C://path)
 workbook = openpyxlWorkbook()

 for i in xrange(0, xlsBook.nsheets):
     xlsSheet = xlsBook.sheet_by_index(i)
     sheet = workbook.active if i == 0 else workbook.create_sheet()
     sheet.title = xlsSheet.name

     for row in xrange(0, xlsSheet.nrows):
         for col in xrange(0, xlsSheet.ncols):
             sheet.cell(row=row+1, column=col+1).value = xlsSheet.cell_value(row, col)

 workbook.save(c://path/workbook.xlsx")
```

This works perfectly.

When attempting to loop through all files, we use:

```
 import xlrd
 from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook as openpyxlWorkbook
 import glob
 import pandas as pd 
 from pandas import ExcelWriter
 import os

 path ="C://path" 
 path2 = "C://path2"

 allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.xls")



 for file_ in allFiles:   
         xlsBook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_)
         workbook = openpyxlWorkbook()

         for i in xrange(0, xlsBook.nsheets):
             xlsSheet = xlsBook.sheet_by_index(i)
             sheet = workbook.active if i == 0 else workbook.create_sheet()
             sheet.title = xlsSheet.name

             for row in xrange(0, xlsSheet.nrows):
                 for col in xrange(0, xlsSheet.ncols):
                     sheet.cell(row=row+1, column=col+1).value = xlsSheet.cell_value(row, col)


    ##workbook.save(os.path.join(path2,file_))
    ##workbook.to_excel(os.path.join(path2,file_))


 workbook.save("C://path/workbook.xlsx")
```

For the first two commented out save methods, workbook.save seems to do absolutely nothing, and to_excel tells me workbook does not have a property called to_excel...is that because I didn't call pandas in the loop?

The final workbook.save was a test- I assumed it would save the final iteration of the loop correctly, since it worked in the script with just one file.

Instead, it creates the file, with all of the worksheets correctly named, but no data in any of the worksheets.

Any idea what I am missing? To be clear, I am looking to have each file named with its original filename at the end of the loop, and a valid xlsx extension.

Comment: If you really do have thousands of files I'd suggest you look at the `write-only` mode that openpyxl provides. `to_excel` is a method of Pandas' DataFrames.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this way instead. Simpler code and it worked when I tested it.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

def converter(filename):
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(filename) # reads file in
    sheet_names = xl.sheet_names # gets the sheet names of the file

    sheets_dict = {} # dictionary with sheet_names as keys and data as values
    for sheet in sheet_names:
        sheets_dict[sheet] = xl.parse(sheet) 

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\you\Desktop\\' + filename.split('\\')[-1][:-4] + '.xlsx') # takes the file path and only returns the file name, now with format xlsx
    for sheet_name, data in sheets_dict.iteritems():
        data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, index = False)
    writer.save()

files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\you\Desktop' + '\*.xls')
for file in files:
    converter(file)
```

Edit: I'm not too familiar with openpyxl but I don't believe it has a `.to_excel` method. I think you were creating a openpyxl workbook but then trying to save it using a pandas method.

Comment: Any ideas on what we were screwing up in the save call above, though?

Comment: one thing, it does not remove the .xls, just adds .xslx on the end...will that cause read errors in other scripts?

Comment: I added [:-4] to the end of the filename.split call so that it will also leave out the last 4 characters on the filename (.xls). That should fix it!